# Hosting project with dev_appserver.py gives different results to deploying to Google Cloud

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, dev-appserver

The project is meant to take some user input and check the connected Google Datastore for a match. When hosted using `dev_appserver.py` everything works as intended.

This is not the case for the live version, uploaded with `gcloud app deploy`. The problem occurs when trying to retrieve an entity, using its key for a `lookup`.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient;

$datastore = new DatastoreClient([
"projectId" => "54327567209-project"
]);

// Retrieving user entities
function lookup_user(DatastoreClient $datastore, string $id) {
  $key = $datastore->key("user", $id);
  $user = $datastore->lookup($key);
  return $user;
}

// Validation
$authErr = "";
$id = $pword = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  // Existence check
  if (!empty($_POST["id"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $pword = $_POST["password"];
    // Attempt to get user from Google Cloud
    $user = lookup_user($datastore, $id); // <---- Error happens here
    // Check if user exists and password matches
    if (!empty($user["name"]) && $user["password"] == $pword) {
      // Removed for debugging
    } else {
      // Id or password authentication fail
      $authErr = "User id or password is invalid";
    }
  } else {
    // Missing id or password
    $authErr = "User id or password is invalid";
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Account Access</h2>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <div>Username: <input name="id" type="text"></input></div>
      <div>Password: <input name="password" type="password"></input></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Login"></div>
      </br>
      <span class="error"><?php echo $authErr; ?></span>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page goes blank when it tries to do the lookup, similar to running `exit()`. There's no error message that I can see. I'm wondering if there's some kind of logging I can turn on to help with this.

Comment: Do you see something in the [Logs Viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer)? You should filter by GAE application and service

Comment: I reproduced you environment using your code sample and it worked for me. I used `"google/cloud-datastore": "^1.11"` and in the `app.yaml` I set the runtime to `runtime: php72` . Are you using GAE Standard or Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `lookup_user()` function. Removing this function and pasting the same code inline fixed the issue.

Comment: Not sure why this fixed the problem. I'll follow the advice given in comments and if I find more information I'll edit the answer.